# whats wrong with my code(sub query - sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting incorrect syntax near ')', c an someone suggest what i am doing wrong? I am trying to get my self familiar with sub queries and thanks in advance!

attached is the sql that i wrote and trying to modify here us the [SQL script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jdvw.jpg)

```
(
  SELECT 
    APP_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM = 0 THEN CUST_APP_ID END) AS PRI_CUST_APP_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM = 1 THEN CUST_APP_ID END) AS SEC_CUST_APP_ID,
    .... 
    ....
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      APP_ID,
      CUST.CUST_ID,
      CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM
      .. 
    FROM CDM_CUST_APP_MTRX CUST_APP_MTRX 
    LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST CUST ON CUST_APP_MTRX.CUST_ID = CUST.CUST_ID
  ) CUST_MTRX
  GROUP BY APP_ID 
) ABC 
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL CUST_ADR_DETL
       ON ABC.PRI_CUST_APP_ID = CUST_ADR_DETL.CUST_APP_ID 
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL CUST_ADR_DETL2
       ON ABC.PRI_CUST_APP_ID = CUST_ADR_DETL2.CUST_APP_ID
```

Comment: Add the quey and the tag for your DBMS

Comment: Paste the query here.

Comment: Dont post images.. Post the query

Comment: Did you try running a select * query? Does that work? It is showing a red underline below a already. Is your GROUP BY clause in the correct place?

Comment: SELECT
APP_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM = 0 THEN CUST_APP_ID END) AS PRI_CUST_APP_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM = 1 THEN CUST_APP_ID END) AS SEC_CUST_APP_ID,
....
....

FROM
(
 SELECT APP_ID,CUST.CUST_ID,CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM..
 FROM CDM_CUST_APP_MTRX CUST_APP_MTRX
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST CUST
ON CUST_APP_MTRX.CUST_ID=CUST.CUST_ID
) CUST_MTRX
GROUP BY APP_ID
) ABC
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL CUST_ADR_DETL ON ABC.PRI_CUST_APP_ID= CUST_ADR_DETL.CUST_APP_ID
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL CUST_ADR_DETL2 ON ABC.PRI_CUST_APP_ID= CUST_ADR_DETL2.CUST_APP_ID

Comment: Thanks for the help Amit, I ran from SELECT APP_ID... to GROUP BY and it is running fine when i try to join with CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL table i am getting the error

Comment: Write one more SELECT * FROM before first bracket in the first line of the query.

Comment: The query would be much more readable if it were not all in upper caps and if you used shorter alias names (e.g. a1 and a2 or adr1 and adr2 for the adresses). Then you should qualify all columns (e.g. app_id, cust_type_ord_num, cust_app_id - which tables do these belong to?). If you want more help on the query (concerning duplicate results), show the whole query and tell us how the tables are related (primary and foreign keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a syntax issue. Write one more SELECT * FROM before first bracket in the first line of the query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    APP_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM = 0 THEN CUST_APP_ID END) AS PRI_CUST_APP_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM = 1 THEN CUST_APP_ID END) AS SEC_CUST_APP_ID
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      APP_ID,
      CUST.CUST_ID,
      CUST_TYPE_ORD_NUM,
      .. 
    FROM CDM_CUST_APP_MTRX CUST_APP_MTRX 
    LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST CUST ON CUST_APP_MTRX.CUST_ID = CUST.CUST_ID
  ) CUST_MTRX
  GROUP BY APP_ID 
) ABC 
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL CUST_ADR_DETL
       ON ABC.PRI_CUST_APP_ID = CUST_ADR_DETL.CUST_APP_ID 
LEFT JOIN CDM_CUST_ADR_DETL CUST_ADR_DETL2
       ON ABC.PRI_CUST_APP_ID = CUST_ADR_DETL2.CUST_APP_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Amit, marked it as "accepted" one more follow up query as i am trying  to learn..after joining the CUST_ADR_DETL and CUST_ADR_DETL2 tables, i am getting same record 4 times, instead of 1 time, can you please suggest?

Comment: Check you inner query first. Is it returning multiple records for something. If not, your left join condition may be requiring more columns in join condition. As a last option, You can anyways use SELECT DISTINCT * FROM in the outer query. But this is required most of the time, when database schema itself has been built in a complicated manner.

Comment: actually i am trying to flatten multiple tables which is like combining multiple rows into single row based on a key.. etc and as i am working on this for the first time finding it difficult...